# Array Buffer Overflow: Leetcode String Compression

Tags: arrays, c, string

I am solving the leetcode 443 problem string compression. I am getting a bug that I've been stuck on for days. The following code produces a Runtime error for heap-buffer-overflow:

```
int compress(char* chars, int charsSize) {
    int newSize = 0;

    if (charsSize < 2)
    return charsSize;

    
    char curr = chars[0];
    int currNum = 1;
    int pointer = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < charsSize; i++)
    {
        if(chars[i] == curr)
        {
            currNum++;
        }
        else
        {
            chars[pointer++] = curr;

            int tempNum = currNum;
            int numDigits = 0; 
            while(tempNum != 0) //get num digits
            {
                tempNum /= 10;
                numDigits++;
            }

            for (int j = numDigits - 1; j >= 0; j-=1) //allocating digits into the return array
            {
                char tempChar = (char)(currNum % 10 + '0');

                if((pointer + j) < charsSize)
                {
                    chars[pointer + j] = tempChar;
                }

                currNum /= 10;
            }
            pointer += numDigits; 
            curr = chars[i]; //resetting for next trial
            currNum = 1;
        }
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

When I comment this line: `chars[pointer + j] = tempChar;` The error goes away. I am not sure why this is happening

I tried working around doing this, and adding checks on the bounds for the array, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: What is the `char *chars` that you're passing into the function and how is it allocated? Your error is that `pointer` grows beyond the allocated length of your array. Try printing out the value of `pointer` at every step in the iteration and see if you can find where it diverges from what you expect the value to be

Comment: (As a sidenote, it's more normal to see the variable you use for indexing an array be called something like `index` (or `ind` or `i`). A "pointer" is a specific term, meaning a memory address that you can dereference with the * operator. I know that sounds nitpicky, but keeping these straight is really important for anything in C)

Comment: Instead of rolling your own code to turn `currNum` into a string, use `sprintf()`.

Comment: Pretty easy to duplicate. https://godbolt.org/z/soGdedYK3 That may be an invalid test case, but you didn't describe the problem or limits in the question.

Comment: It looks like you forgot about this point in the instructions: **If the group's length is 1, append the character to s.**. You're appending the length when it's 1. That will cause the size to increase if there are enough characters that have length=1.

Comment: FYI, this is an ambiguous compression scheme if the input can contain digits. The output `12` could result from either `12` or `11`.

Comment: It's a minor nitpick, but getting the number of digits in a number feels like something that could be broken out into a separate function.

Comment: From looking at the problem statement: https://leetcode.com/problems/string-compression/ AFAICT, this has _nothing_ to do with parsing input digits. It is about simple RLE (run length encoding) of a string. Given a string: `aabbbcdef` the output should be: `a2b3cdef` So, I don't understand your code's complexity. It can be a simple _single_ loop.